# How can I create a file which documents only "Public" APIs in Doxygen

Tags: documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

I have a project which I am working on which is a *library*. I need to document the internals of the library code for my own purposes, but also need to deliver an API document to my users on how they should use the library.

So, in the document I wish to give to them, I want to include only the "public" functions, structures, variables, etc - and *not* the *internal* ones.

Is there a way I can do this in Doxygen? Can I delineate what is "public" and what is "private"? Can I generate a document which contains only the "public" API for my users, and a separate one with the "private" design details for my own use?

NOTE: This is straight C, not C++ - and my use of the terms "public" and "private" have nothing to do with "public" and "private" class members.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on your need, there are several ways of doing this:

- You can use the [`\internal`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdinternal) tag
- You can use the [`\private`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdprivate) tag together with [`EXTRACT_PRIVATE=NO`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extract_private) in doxyfile
- and probably others involving one of the various `EXTRACT_` configuration variables.